# filter object from aggregation in mongo (filter inner array)

Tags: mongodb

I have an aggregation that my goal is to remove an object that does not meet the criteria

1- first stage is to meet the date criteria

2- after that each value could have an array and I would like to remove the whole object if one of the value in the inner array is NOT meet the date criteria (lte)

if I can do that in the lookup step it will be better

playground :
https://mongoplayground.net/p/lF0UATwdDVJ

the data: **should return the object of id 3,4**

```
[
  /** given date : 2020-10-01T00:00:00Z*/
  /** should return : id: 3,4*/
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
      "ref": null
    },
    "date": ISODate("2020-09-01T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": {
      "ref": null
    },
    "date": ISODate("2021-01-20T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "data": {},
    "date": ISODate("2020-09-10T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "data": {
      "ref": 1
    },
    "date": ISODate("2019-08-11T00:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

id 1 will not be returned because id 2 hold id 1 as ref and the date of id 2 is newer then the first match

I tried the following aggregation but I still got id 1

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "date": {
        "$lte": ISODate("2020-10-01T00:00:00Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "data.ref",
      "as": "refs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $or: [
        {
          refs: []
        },
        {
          "refs": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "date": {
                "$lte": ISODate("2020-10-01T00:00:00Z")
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      date: 1
    }
  }
])
```